# Hide a column in select query of Oracle

Tags: oracle

Since it is mandatory to specify the all columns in group clause to select clause I can't avoid it. But is there any way to hide?

```
SELECT c.name, 
       p.company, 
       SUM(p.qty) as "Total Shares",
       AVG(p.qty*p.price) as "Average Of Total Shares"
  FROM purchase p, client c
 WHERE c.clno = p.clno
 GROUP BY company, 
          name;
```

I need to hide p.company. Can anyone suggest an idea?

Comment: It's not mandatory. The thing is you can not have any other column in select apart from the ones in group by. So if you want to hide just don't include it in select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't include it in the select clause ( even though it is present in the Group BY Clause ).

```
SELECT 
c.name,  
SUM(p.qty) as "Total Shares",
AVG(p.qty*p.price) as "Average Of Total Shares" 
FROM purchase p, client c 
WHERE c.clno = p.clno 
GROUP BY company, name;
```